# I am having trouble with the logic flow of this code, and the resulting incorrect output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a graph based on BTC historical price data from coinbase.
Part of this requires that I make the data retrieved from coinbase usable for chart js.

I am having trouble with this aspect.

```
function getBitcoinHistory(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json",
    success: function(historicalPrice){
        console.log(JSON.parse(historicalPrice))

            var dateArray = []

            dateToday = year+"-"+month+"-"+day
            dataStartDate = year+"-"+month-1+"-"+day-1

            console.log("month is "+month+" day is "+day)

            //set up month and day first
            dataMonth=month-1
            dataDay=day-1
            console.log("data date starts at 0"+dataMonth+"-"+dataDay)

            //loop through all of the dates from oldest to newest
            for(var i = 0; i < 31; i++){
                //formatting correctly 
                if(dataMonth<10 && dataDay<10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i)]; console.log("2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i))}
                if(dataMonth<10 && dataDay>=10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-"+(dataDay+i)]; console.log("2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-"+(dataDay+i))}
                if(dataMonth>=10 && dataDay<10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i)]; console.log("2019-"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i))}
                if(dataMonth>=10 && dataDay>=10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-"+(dataMonth)+"-"+(dataDay+i)]; console.log("2019-"+(dataMonth)+"-"+(dataDay+i))}

                //if the date does not exist then it must be the next month
                if(dateArray[i]==undefined){
                    dataMonth=dataMonth+1
                    dataDay=1
                    if(month>12){
                        month=1
                    }
                    if(dataMonth<10 && dataDay<10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i)]; console.log("2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i))}
                    if(dataMonth<10 && dataDay>=10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-"+(dataDay+i)]; console.log("2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-"+(dataDay+i))}
                    if(dataMonth>=10 && dataDay<10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i)]; console.log("2019-"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i))}
                    if(dataMonth>=10 && dataDay>=10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-"+(dataMonth)+"-"+(dataDay+i)]; console.log("2019-"+(dataMonth)+"-"+(dataDay+i))}
                }
                console.log("Data at "+i+" is: "+dateArray[i])
                //console.log("2019-"+(month-1)+"-"+(day+i))
            }
        }
    })
```

I am hoping to have the dates be stored in an array in the correct format, but instead everything gets very weird at the point when the month changes. It will skip a few days and then also start adding extra 0s to the front of numbers even when it shouldnt...
I am lost.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Could help to use Template strings for better readability https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Could you share what you expect to see as a result?

Comment: As a result I would like to see the date formatted as 
2019-06-29
2019-06-30
2019-07-01
2019-07-02
etc..

Comment: Also, where do you define the `year`, `month`, `day` variables?

Comment: This code looks wrong: `if(dataMonth<10 && dataDay<10){dateArray[i]=JSON.parse(historicalPrice).bpi["2019-0"+(dataMonth)+"-0"+(dataDay+i)]; `  You're seeing if dataDay needs a leading zero... but you're building the date with (dataDay+i)..... looks like you'll get a date 2019-07-031'

Comment: Could also help to see an example of the response from the server that you are working with.

Comment: I find all this code particularly difficult to read. Have you considered just using a library that handles all this for you?

Comment: I define the day, month and year variables higher up in the code.

var date = new Date()
year = date.getFullYear()
month = date.getMonth()+1
day = date.getDate()

Comment: KenOn would you mind elaborating on why the code is wrong?

I appreciate your time

Comment: Dave Newton I have not considered that as I do not know about that. Would you mind elaborating? I am a bit of a newbie

Comment: Like have been pointed out, you should really look into moment.js. It generally not a good idea to write your own data handling unless you are sure you know what you are doing. It a very tricky task, even fro senior programmers. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: okay! Thank you Einar Ólafsson . I will look into this.

Comment: Why aren't you using something like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to control dates in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some have noted in the comments, there seems to be a bit of a readability issue, especially with all this date parsing / formatting. I would strongly consider looking into moment.js (or similar), where the primary date format you seem to desire is essentially iso8601 (so parsing too and from this format should be particularly painless!) :)

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/

---

Nested `if`s are generally undesired (if you can split the contents of an `if` into a separate function, then you should *usually* do so)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is expecting everymonth has 31 days, you need to contrl that and im sure it will perform different at the moment it goes on for the next month :/

Comment: This would fit more like a comment, in my opinion, as you're raising a possible cause for the issue, but not an applicable solution.